# Change datatype of an item of an object in a collection

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda

I am able to change the datatype of a particular property of an object on the fly, but I am not super happy with my approach, as I know that the object I am going to use in my project has like two dozen properties in there.

**What I attempted**

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NammaClass nammaClass = new NammaClass();

            List<NammaClass> listNamma = new List<NammaClass>
            {
                new NammaClass{quant= 1, dattim = "01/01/2020"},
                new NammaClass{quant= 2, dattim = "02/02/2022"}
            };

            var newList = (from user in listNamma
                           select new
                           {
                               quant = user.quant,//I Don't want to write this
                               dattim = DateTime.Parse(user.dattim)
                           }).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class NammaClass
    {
        public int quant;
        public string dattim;
    }
```

**The problem** with above approach is that I am forced to use all the properties of the `NammaClass` object just to be able to change the datatype of one property, is there an elegant way to have the whole object but just one property's datatype changed.

Comment: If you want strong (=compile-time-)types result there's no way to do this, as the compiler can't know which of the properties you want to retain and which not.

Comment: Why you store it as string at all in `NammaClass` if it's actually a DateTime?

Comment: Not related to the problem but DateTime.Parse can throw exception if it can not convert the input. If possible please prefer TryParse.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - This is just an illustration, I am receiving this object from another library and the datatype is string, which I would like to change it to datetime to be able to perform formatting such as ToShortDateString()

Comment: @VivekShukla: No, there is no auto-deep-clone feature in .net, you have to implement it yourself. In theory you could use reflection, but it's not very efficient and could also cause issues. So the easiest it to provide a factory method or constructor when you can pass in the object from the library and get back yours. Then you can simplify the conversion to: `var newList = listNamma.Select(ConvertNamma).ToList()`. Here `ConvertNamma` is a method that takes `NammaClass` and returns your desired target type. So there's the mapping "magic"(boilerplate code).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am trying to avoid reflection, and seems like I would either end up doing what I started with i.e. using select in linq or create a method and let the func refer it.

Comment: @VivekShukla: Yes, of course there is no magic auto conversion from type1 to type2. You can use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) or other library that contains the boilerplate code but under the hood it's the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C# 9 or later, you can use Records and the `with` expression:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#nondestructive-mutation

> If you need to copy an instance with some modifications, you can use a with expression to achieve nondestructive mutation. A with expression makes a new record instance that is a copy of an existing record instance, with specified properties and fields modified.

Example:

`var newList = listNamma.Select(x => x with { dattim = DateTime.Parse(x.dattim) });`

Comment: very interesting, it seems that the constructor of an object may need to go through changes to return record? The object I am receiving is from another library built a long time ago, so certainly not on c# 9